# Deleting a database row with mysql - getting an error?

Tags: mysql, delete-row, sql-delete

Here's the code:

```
mysql_query("DELETE " . $_GET['id'] . " FROM forum_favorites WHERE thread_id='" . $_GET['id'] . "' AND user='" . $userinfo['username'] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '77 FROM
>   forum_favorites WHERE thread_id='77'
>   AND user='user'' at line 1

Anyone knows what's up here? I've been stuck here for hours now and i just can't figure out what the heck's wrong? The database name and the column names are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `" . $_GET['id'] . "` between `DELETE` and `FROM`:

```
DELETE FROM forum_favorites etc...
```

See the [documentation for DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) for more information.

Note that your code may also be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I'd suggest reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) and the answers there.

Comment: I am like 100% sure i tried removing it before, but it didn't work. Heh, well thanks. And yea i've fixed that now!

Answer (score 1):

```
$thread_id=intval($_GET['id']);
$username=mysql_real_escpe_string($userinfo['username']);

$sql="DELETE FROM forum_favorites WHERE thread_id=$thread_id AND user='$username'";
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The username is already validated and don't have to be validated twice. This would work for the id aswell, right? $thread_id = htmlentities($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES); But to be honest, your "fix" looks simpler.

Comment: @Nike hehe you messed everything up :) mysql_real_escpe_string does no validation at all. Nor htmlentities does. Escaping is just a part of SQL syntax. No validation can replace it. To be placed into SQL query, every string must be enclosed in quotes and, therefore, escaped. No exceptions. For the thread_id htmlentities will help you nothing. Especially if you don't enclose it in quotes. Actually, **html** entities function has nothing to do with **sql** query. Go figure ;)

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what i meant when i said validation. Sorry xD Yeah i know it doesn't have anything to do with sql, but it does escape quotes, somehow! No matter what i enter now, it just ignores it and shoots it up to the database, just like it's suppose to.

Comment: Notice that i added ", ENT_QUOTES" to the htmlentities tag. I believe that affects it somehow. I'm still learning, so i might be wrong, but my teacher in school actually taught me that that was, well, ONE of many CORRECT ways of escaping (not validating, heh) a string. Still, sorry if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Nick I am sorry but your teacher knows nothing. As e result, you know nothing as well. One cannot "validate" a string preliminarily. It can be done right before placing into query only. And the only SQL preparation can be escaping and nothing else. You also spoil your data, making &quot; from quote.

Comment: Heyy, i'm not completely useless. I just didn't know how to do this. Actually, that's one of like 2-3 things my teacher has learned me about php/mysql. I've worked mostly with it at home. But, if i do use your method to escape the string, what happens if a user enters somehting like <?php harmful_script_here(); ?> ? Since your method doesn't spoil the data with &quote; etc, it just shoots the string right up to the database without changing anything. So, what can i do to avoid the string from the database to be executed when printed out?

Comment: @Nick such kind of string will never be executed. The only executable code in the string can be Javascript. To prevent it from the execution htmlspecialchars() function must be used, yes. But it shouldn't be messed with SQL escaping. It's totally different matters. sql escaping cannot be replaced with HTML one. Sql escaping doesn't change the data, but html one does. So, it would be bad idea to escape html anywhere beside right before output.

Comment: Okey, so why will "that kind" of code never be executed? I don't see the difference... i mean, both php and javascript contains such characters. Okey, so if i got you right now, your telling me that i should just escape the string when writing to the database, and when printing the text out, use htmlspecialchars() to change quotes etc. to html text? Sounds pretty good to me. :)